# Django URL ordering

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the Django sitemap framework to set up a sitemap but I'm getting an issue with setting up the sitemap URL.

Here is my projects urls.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^debug-toolbar/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    )

    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
        url(r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt")),
        url(r'^500/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="500.html")),
        url(r'^404/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="404.html")),
        url(r'^', include('hunt.urls')),
    )
else:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
        url(r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt")),
        url(r'^500/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="500.html")),
        url(r'^404/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="404.html")),
        url(r'^', include('hunt.urls')),
    )
```

Here is my hunt apps urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('hunt.views',
    url(r'^$', top100, name='top100'),
    url(r'^explore/$', explore, name='explore'),
    url(r'^monthly/$', monthlytop10, name='monthlytop10'),
    url(r'^trending/$', trending, name='trending'),
    url(r'^genres/$', genres, name='genres'),
    url(r'^genres/(?P<slug>.+)/$', genre_view, name='genre_view'),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^contact/thanks/$', thanks, name='thanks'),
    url(r'^faq/$', faq, name='faq'),
    url(r'^songs/(?P<slug>.+)$', song_search, name='song_search'),
    url(r'^loadmore/dj/$', loadmore_dj, name='loadmore_dj'),
    url(r'^loadmore/genre/$', loadmore_genre, name='loadmore_genre'),
    url(r'^loadmore/month/$', loadmore_month, name='loadmore_month'),
    url(r'^loadmore/trending/$', loadmore_trending, name='loadmore_trending'),
    url(r'^vote/dj/$', vote_dj, name='vote_dj'),
    url(r'^vote/genre/$', vote_genre, name='vote_genre'),
    url(r'^vote/month/$', vote_month, name='vote_month'),
    url(r'^vote/trending/$', vote_trending, name='vote_trending'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)/$', dj, name='dj'),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I try to access sitemap.xml I'm getting an error

```
404 Page Not Found
No DJ matches the given query.
```

This means it tried to access the last URL in my hunt app. Why is it trying to access the DJ Page even though it comes after sitemap.xml URL?

EDIT -
As per eran's suggestion, I ran the command `show_urls` of `django_extensions`. Here is the output of that

```
/   hunt.views.top100   top100
/404/   django.views.generic.base.TemplateView
/500/   django.views.generic.base.TemplateView
/<slug>/    hunt.views.dj   dj
/contact/   hunt.views.contact  contact
/contact/thanks/    hunt.views.thanks   thanks
/explore/   hunt.views.explore  explore
/faq/   hunt.views.faq  faq
/genres/    hunt.views.genres   genres
/genres/<slug>/ hunt.views.genre_view   genre_view
/loadmore/dj/   hunt.views.loadmore_dj  loadmore_dj
/loadmore/genre/    hunt.views.loadmore_genre   loadmore_genre
/loadmore/month/    hunt.views.loadmore_month   loadmore_month
/loadmore/trending/ hunt.views.loadmore_trending    loadmore_trending
/media/<path>   django.views.static.serve
/monthly/   hunt.views.monthlytop10 monthlytop10
/robots.txt django.views.generic.base.TemplateView
/sitemap.xml    django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap
/songs/<slug>   hunt.views.song_search  song_search
/static/<path>  django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve
/trending/  hunt.views.trending trending
/vote/dj/   hunt.views.vote_dj  vote_dj
/vote/genre/    hunt.views.vote_genre   vote_genre
/vote/month/    hunt.views.vote_month   vote_month
/vote/trending/ hunt.views.vote_trending    vote_trending
```

Comment: You should perhaps try this instead, more standard:

    url(r'', include('hunt.urls')),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a `sitemaps.xml` file in my templates folder that I was using before. Deleting that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to that `show_urls` output, the URLpattern for `hunt.views.dj` is taking precedence, because the `r'^(?P<slug>.+)/$'` regex appears before the `sitemap.xml` regex. The former regex will match a request to "sitemap.xml", so Django will never reach the pattern that's specifically meant for sitemap.xml. For that matter, it will never reach /contact/, /explore/, /faq/, etc.

I suspect that's happening because your project-wide `urls.py` appends to `urlpatterns` ("`urlpatterns +=`") rather than setting it directly. Looks like you didn't paste all of the imports from the project-wide `urls.py`, but I would assume one of the things you're importing includes a `patterns` object; otherwise you'd be getting a `NameError` at import time (`name 'patterns' is not defined`).

You should be able to fix it by changing this...

`urlpatterns += patterns('',`

...to this...

`urlpatterns = patterns('',`

But I have no way of knowing for certain, because I don't know what else you've imported in the project's `urls.py`.

Comment: The other URLs, `/contact/`, `/explore/`, `/faq/` etc. work fine.

Comment: Mind adding the imports for the app's urls.py as well?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your sitemap and robots.txt urls are the only ones that don't end in a trailing slash. Many web servers will redirect `myurl.com/item` to `myurl.com/item/` - for example, this is the [preferred practice when using Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) (search for "Trailing Slash Problem"). Try doing a curl to the url without a trailing slash - do you get a 301 redirect? If so then it is likely redirecting to the URL which DOES include a trailing slash, which is not matched by a pattern in your urls.py. Try adding trailing slashes to your regular expressions, or setting `APPEND_SLASH = True` in settings.py